# securing jax-rs with roles

Tags: java, web-services, security, rbac

I'm currently looking into securing jax-rs web services.
The following URL is very interesting: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24983/secure.htm#RESTF256.
I am especially looking at the annotations-based security of web services. Defining per method the roles that are allowed looks very straightforward.
I have however 4 questions related to this topic:

1. defining and mapping roles

I'm wondering: where does one define the roles of users and how does one make the mapping of users to roles when using annotation-based security?
If someone could point me to an example with code, that would be great, I'm not having a lot of luck finding one.

2. Libraries/frameworks

Are there any libraries/frameworks that you know of that could be used for securing jax-rs services? I don't have the impression e.g. that Apache Shiro is really suited for web services? I would prefer not using Spring security, it's a bit too heavy for what I'm doing.

3. Database design

Also, for an authentication/authorization scheme using RBAC, with users having roles and roles having assigned permissions, how do you design this on a database level?

4. Permissions

When looking at the RBAC principle, you have permissions assigned to roles. However, using annotation based security, you only define "access" to methods on a role level. How do you check if a user has permissions? Or do you just use roles and ignore permissions altogether when using an RBAC principle?

Thanks for any input you can provide!

**UPDATE1**: Am I correct in assuming that, if you define your users and what roles they have yourself in a database instead of e.g. in web.xml, that it is probably easier/better to use SecurityContext for checking if users are in roles, instead of web.xml or annotations?
This would allow you to use your own securitycontext object which can make calls to a database for validating role membership?